# Confluent Kafka: Consumer does not read from beginning for all partitions in a topic

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform

I have a topic with 40 partitions. Settings are such:

```
def on_assign (c,ps):
    for p in ps:
        p.offset=0
    print ps
    c.assign(ps)

conf = {'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092'
        'enable.auto.commit' : False,
        'group.id' : 'confluent_consumer',
        'default.topic.config': {'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest'}
        }
consumer = Consumer(**conf)
consumer.subscribe(['topic.source'], on_assign=on_assign)

msg = consumer.poll(timeout=100000)
print "Topic is %s: | Partition is %d: | Offset is : %d | key is :%s " % (msg.topic(), msg.partition(), msg.offset(), msg.key())
```

I want to read from offset 0 for all partitions of the topic `topic.source`. But I don't see it happening for all partitions. For some partitions it reads from a specific offset which I'm assuming is the committed offset, changing the `group.id` every time doesn't help either. How can I read from beginning for all partitions of this topic irrespective of the committed offsets?

I printed `ps` in `on_assign()` and it printed something like this for all 40 partitions:

```
[TopicPartition{topic=topic.source,partition=0,offset=0,error=None},TopicPartition{topic=topic.source,partition=1,offset=0,error=None}....] and so on
```

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5):

If you use set `group.id` to a new value or use a group that has not committed any offset with `auto.offset.reset` set to `earliest` then the consumer will start from the beginning of the partition.

That said, the beginning might not be offset 0. Depending on your broker's log retention settings, Kafka can be deleting messages thus the 1st available message in your partitions could be at any offset.

Comment: Hi Mickael, thanks for your answer. Is there any command/tool to know what the beginning offset of a topic partition is(In case the previous messages are deleted due to retention policy)?

Comment: If you want to check on the broker, you can go into kafka's `log.dirs` and find the directory for the partitions. Inside there should be a `*.log` file. The name of the file should indicate the first offset. For example, if you see `00000000000000000216.log` then 216 is the 1st offset. Depending on your settings there might be several log files, take the smallest name.

Comment: Hi Mickael! Thank you, I found the log.dirs and I'm able to see the *.log files